# AuthService is not available in AppCues for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Appcues development and referring to the example given in this page for AngularJS.

[Appcues Example for AngularJS](https://my.appcues.com/install)

I noticed that the AuthService is being used in the controller code but the AuthService is not provided anywhere. Due to this, the code is unable to infer the AuthService and it is not possible to load the page.

[image]

Could anyone suggest how AuthService should be inferred so that the page can be rendered?

Please let me know if I need to provide any specific details.

Thanks,
Ramesh, INDIA

Comment: can you please check console ???

Comment: have you done this ... `angular.module('yourapp').run(function($rootScope, $window) {
   $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
       if ($window.Appcues) {
          $window.Appcues.start();
        }
     });
   });`

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for the controller is wrong, it should be, Remove the extra **`)`** after the controller name

```
.controller('LoginController',function($scope,$rootScope,AUTH_EVENTS,AuthService){

}
```

Comment: but on the page : https://my.appcues.com/install it given like that only ....controller('LoginController'), function($scope, $rootScope, AUTH_EVENTS, AuthService) {...it there is nay error than javascript report issue in console

Comment: thats not the way